# creating bubble graph in python

Tags: python-3.x, bubble-chart

I want to create a bubble graph like the one shown here:

https://www.pythonprogramming.in/how-to-create-a-categorical-bubble-plot-in-python.html

However, my data frame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company1':['h1', 'n1', 's1',
                               'hh1', 'ss1'],                   
                   'Company2':['ps1', 'ps2', 'ps3',
                               'ps4'],
                   'Count':[0.33, 1.13, 3.33, 1.16, 34.6, 25.1, 21.0, 36.5, 5.16, 3.97,
                             19.8,  26.5, 3.16, 12.8, 12.0, 3.6, 45.2, 56.8, 43.9, 32.1]
                   })
```

So basically, as a heat map it would like that I would have company 1 on one axis and company 2 on another:

[image]

But I want to create a bubble graph like the one shown in the link I shared. How can I do that with my data frame. Help will be appreciated.